# obj file cannot be opened or imported to blender. how to change the type of mesh?

Tags: mesh, import, error, obj

recently I have been working on a project that requires the use of obj files but sadly obj file exported from photoshop cannot be opened on blender if I where to import I instantly get this error:

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj\__init__.py", line 151, in execute
    return import_obj.load(context, **keywords)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj\import_obj.py", line 1249, in load
    create_materials(filepath, relpath, material_libs, unique_materials,
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj\import_obj.py", line 444, in create_materials
    load_material_image(context_material, context_mat_wrap,
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj\import_obj.py", line 173, in load_material_image
    map_offset = tuple(map(float_func, map_offset))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'Layer'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

plus the mesh quality is not ok, here is an example image about it.
[image: mesh image]

this is how it looks like in an online obj viewer.

my desired mesh shape is something like this:
[image]

here is the example.obj file that contains the example object used in this post: [example.obj](https://easyupload.io/6uzi05)

Comment: What exact version of Blender are you using? - The obj (wavefront) importer was rewritten in C++ in versions later than 3.0 and is now built into Blender rather than being an addon, so it might be worth trying a more recent Blender version. (Latest is 3.4 as of a few days ago.)

Comment: thanks @John_Eason that solved my first issue. now only one issue left the mesh issue i have no idea how to solve it tho

Comment: That mesh is a real mess and the mported textures don't appear to be used on it! Not that surprising if it was created in Photoshop to be honest. Is it just supposed to be a single oval-shaped plane with zero thickness? If so, why not just create it directly in Blender?

Comment: actually this was supposed to be just a small example that still recreates the issues of a really complex obj file (i created the complex file by simply extruding a png into 3d using photoshop but the thing is that the object itself has holes) and is not easy to draw

Answer (score 0):

As they commented previously, it might be worth giving a shot to more recent Blender versions. I had no problems importing your .obj in blender 3.3, but its size was 1956 x 2954 m! No wonder it might cause you trouble. [image: I can't seem to see it on the editor either!]

I suppose the second problem was retopologizing the mesh. You should look into topology stuff! It'll help you a lot with those holes in your mesh you mentioned. Photoshop's 3D viewer is nice, although really messy when it comes to 3D modelling.

[image: I suppose this is what you wanted!]

You can achieve this creating a simple plane, using the subsurf modifier and Triangulate Faces in Edit Mode. Hope it helps!

Comment: i am having a lot of trouble making this work can you help me with this i need to make this mesh look more homogeneous and triangular just like the desired mesh shown in my question? i will send you the real obj file hopefully it turns out to be possible to fix. and it would be great if you can also send the output along with the procedure. image.obj: [link](https://easyupload.io/jjsd0k)